# how to build and save forms dynamically in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

In a pluggable architecture for asp.net mvc, i need to build a form where any plug-in can add its form elements to a form through application wide events. When the form is submitted back to server, values of elements must be saved by relevant plug-in which added the form elements.
Any ideas on how to build and save forms like that?

Comment: Dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277286/using-xml-config-file

Comment: @Haroldis, a form is not a page in asp.net mvc.

Comment: This is pretty broad.  Your touching on pluggable components, message bussing, dynamic input binding, dynamic UI and I'm sure some type of configuration logic needs to be here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do is after receiving the model of forms elements through your action, you can call the events and send the event data from your action methods to the events with the arguments in place, and those events would then take care of the saving, if this is the direction you want to move in. Or, alternatively, you can have the form running as an iframe and the content of that iframe will be your aspx web forms file which can then take care of the events as they normally would in any web forms aspx program/file.

The second option is what I actually use when I need to mix mvc and aspx :)

Let me know if this answers your question, remember aspx and mvc can run in the same project and even the same page if you put the aspx in an iframe :)... Which is really two pages but gives the illusion of there being one page.

Cool?

Comment: Glad I can help, I still don't understand why jfar and haroldis did nothing but tear apart ur question, nod nod!! :) cheers